# Automatically crop PDFs

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a program that can crop out the surrounding white space of a PDF (i.e. chop  off the margins). If possible, free, can take a batch of files as input, and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I know that I can crop a PDF manually using [BRISS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/):

[image]

but I want to have it done automatically.

Comment: Consider looking at OCR applications. They would do this as part of the OCR process.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to do this from the command line, (provided that you also have [GhostScript](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost) installed on your path). From the [formats page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php):

> PDF - RW - Portable Document Format:  Requires [Ghostscript](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost) to read. By
>   default, ImageMagick sets the page size to the MediaBox. Some PDF
>   files, however, have a CropBox or TrimBox that is smaller than the
>   MediaBox and may include white space, registration or cutting marks
>   outside the CropBox or TrimBox. To force ImageMagick to use the
>   CropBox or TrimBox rather than the MediaBox, use -define (e.g. -define
>   pdf:use-cropbox=true or -define pdf:use-trimbox=true). Use -density to
>   improve the appearance of your PDF rendering (e.g. -density 300x300).
>   Use -alpha remove to remove transparency. To specify direct conversion
>   from Postscript to PDF, use -define delegate:bimodel=true. Use -define
>   pdf:fit-page=true to scale to the page size.

- Free (Libra & FLOSS)
- Cross Platform
- Can be called from scripts/batch files - even has language bindings
- Huge list of output formats
- Can add watermarks
- *More like a 4 course meal than making the tea*

Comment: The exact command would have been nice.

Comment: This converts the PDF to raster.